# Change Page Header color to the same as menu

Tags: jquery

i am building a one page website, i have a horizontal menu each li have a different color on mouse over or click, that works ok. However, i want to change the page header to the same color as the menu when the menu is clicked. So far i have this script:

```
 JQuery
  $(document).ready(function(e) { //script to change menu color
     $('[id*="button"]').click(function(){
       $('.nav li').removeClass();
  $(this).toggleClass('selected'+$('a',this).attr('class'));
       });
  });
  $(document).ready(function(e) { //script to change page header color
     $(".nav li").on('click', function(){
       $('.page-header').addClass('selected'+$('a',this).attr('class'));
        $('.page-header').removeClass('selected');
    });
 });

 HTML
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="nav">
           <li id="yellowbutton"><a href="#" class="yellow">Home</a></li>
           <li id="redbutton"><a href="#" class="red">Product</a></li>
           <li id="purplebutton"><a href="#" class="purple">Service</a></li>
           <li id="greenbutton"><a href="#" class="green">Support</a></li> 
           <li id="orangebutton"><a href="#" class="orange">Contact</a></li>
           <li id="bluebutton"><a href="#" class="blue">About</a></li>
       </ul>  
   </div><!-- menu Ends Here -->
```

The problem is the script to change the page header is not working properly. Can some please show me where i an going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are just adding classes. You have to

```
$('.page-header').css('background-color', $('a',this).attr('class'))
```

Note that there are multiple code smells in your code.

Comment: this works but how do you handle if it the background is linear-gradient?

Comment: this is the css for the background of the menu li

Comment: .selectedyellow 
 {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#e5e500, #b2b200);
 }